# Can we use TLS over TCP protocol?

Tags: http, ssl, tcp, tls1.2

if my application uses(for instance online shopping application ) plain tcp protocol for connecting to our partners' hosts who process payments, tcp is not secure way for transmitting data?  TLS X.X or SSL will be applicable only for https (Application Layer protocols)? or TLS/SSL its self a protocol which can work on top of TCP?

Also, Say for example a payment processor shared http endpoint which is TLS enabled one. and I am connecting it with tcp.
--- how the encryption/decryption happens at both ends ?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

TLS is a protocol which works on top of TCP. HTTPS is HTTP on top of TLS on top of TCP. There are other protocols which use TLS on top of TCP like IMAPS, FTPS etc. One can also establish a TLS session on top of an existing TCP connection and transfer data with ones own application protocol. One can even do this after other data where already exchanged over the plain TCP connection, as done within SMTP or IMAP (TLS only after STARTTLS command).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. if my server exposed Http endpoint and client is hittin it with tcp protocol(TLS enabled). what would be the impact? is there any disadvantage?

Comment: @SudhaRajamanickam: If the server can only do plain HTTP and the client is trying to do TLS than the server will try to interpret the first message in the TLS handshake from the client (i.e. ClientHello) as a HTTP request and fail. The server will likely return some HTTP error response due to this which then gets interpreted by the client as a TLS response which usually results in inconsistent and strange error messages. There are actual several questions on SO where exactly this happened.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich That's why there are different ports for HTTP and HTTPS.

Comment: @RonInbar: Kind of but no. Both with plain HTTP and with HTTPS (i.e. HTTP over TLS) the client starts sending data and the server could easily distinguish from the first bytes if plain HTTP (starts with HTTP request) is spoken or HTTPS (starts with TLS ClientHello).  Its more convenient though to have different ports for both.